# Computed property causes application crash

Tags: macos, swift

I'm porting the Apple class [ImageAndTextCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SourceView/Listings/ImageAndTextCell_m.html) to swift and use it inside a NSTableView, it was a trivial task but when I click on table row the application crashes.

I suppose the crash is due to a deallocation problem but I don't understand how to fix it.

The app crashes with the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ADDRESS (code=EXC_i386_GPFLT), no other message is present so debugging the error is hard

I've isolated the code to easily reproduce the crash.

My ImageAndTextCell is shown below, it declares an icon property and access to it using the computed property image

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class ImageAndTextCell : NSTextFieldCell {
    private var icon : NSImage?

    override var image : NSImage! {
    get {
        return icon
    }
    set {
        if newValue !== icon {
            icon = newValue
            if let im = newValue {
                im.size = NSMakeSize(CGFloat(16.0), CGFloat(16.0))
            }
        }
    }
    }

    deinit { println(" is being deinitialized") }

    override func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject! {
        var cell = super.copyWithZone(zone) as ImageAndTextCell
        cell.icon = icon
        return cell
    }
}
```

The Application delegate is

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    var items = [String]()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        items.append("/Users/dave/trash/test.txt")
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView!) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject! {
        return self.items[row]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, willDisplayCell cell:AnyObject!, forTableColumn tableColumn:NSTableColumn!, row:NSInteger) {
        let item = self.items[row]
        var fieldCell = cell as NSTextFieldCell
        fieldCell.drawsBackground = false
        // commenting the line below the app works fine but obviously the cell doesn't show the image
        fieldCell.image = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().iconForFile(item)
    }
}
```

copyWithZone and deinit are called every time I click on the row so I suppose some pointer is released before the time

The table cell 'custom class' is set inside Interface Builder to ImageAndTextCell

Any idea?

Comment: I am also getting crash in ImageAndTextCell on 10.10 OSX. Retaining and releasing the image in tableview delegate fixed my problem.